# What is "bank account UNN"?

Tags: app-store-connect, accounts

This question is about **iTunes Connect**, particularly **Agreements, Tax, and Banking** section. When I open this section I see the red message:

> Our records indicate that your banking information is incomplete. Please access your banking information and update as necessary.

Screen:
[image: iTunes Connect Error]

So, following this recommendation I go to **Bank Info > Edit > View/Edit Existing Bank Account > Edit Bank Account Info**

There I see a new field which wasn't there when I first entered the banking information. It's named **UNN**. Quick help:

> Enter the nine-digit UNN for your account.

Screen:
[image: iTunes Connect, Edit Bank Account Info, UNN]

So the question is, what is the UNN associated with a bank account?

I've called to my bank and they didn't know anything. Also, I've already asked this question on [Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61868), but there was no response for a week.

Comment: Questions such as this that deal with subjects that are likely country- or region-specific would be more easily answered (and discovered) if the country is specified in the question.

Comment: @tubedogg, but how could I know that this question is country-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNN code is a Taxpayer’s code (INN, UNN or UNP code (natural persons don't have codes UNN or INN) needed for payment transactions in/to Belarus. ([Source](https://www.seb.lt/eng/private/daily-banking/bank-account-and-transfers/international-money-transfer/transfer-russia#transfer-belarus))

Comment: Looks right, thanks for the link. I will check this and if I'll have any problems I'll update the question.